# ERROR: self signed certificate in certificate chain ( on turbo deploy )

Tags: reactjs, certificate, ssl-certificate, react-native

I am trying to complete a course on Youtube where you build an Instagram clone in React Native. When I run "turbo deploy" to deploy the app (turbo360) I get the error: ERROR: self signed certificate in certificate chain

I dont even know what a self signed certificate is and I dont know where I could look for it or change something.

I read that it can be kinda ignored by adding:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
```

but I dont know where to add it.

Thanks in advance.